# How to make jquery autocomplete to work in latest free jqgrid

Tags: jquery-mobile, jqgrid, jquery-autocomplete, free-jqgrid

I tried to use edittype: custom  in latest free jqgrid in Github.
Autocomplete window width is same as column width and is too small in mobile.:

[image: narrow]

How to make autocomplete dropdown wider, more native in mobile?

Complete testcase:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/css/ui.jqgrid.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {
            $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
            $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
            $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
        });
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://rawgit.com/commadelimited/autoComplete.js/master/jqm.autoComplete-1.5.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var mydata = [
                { id: 0, Name: "Indiana", Category: "IN" },
                { id: 1, Name: "California", Category: "CA" },
                { id: 2, Name: "Pennsylvania", Category: "PA" },
                { id: 3, Name: "Texas", Category: "TX" }
            ];
            var lastSel;
            var grid = $("#list");

            grid.jqGrid({
                data: mydata,
                datatype: 'local',
                colModel: [
                    {
                        name: 'Name', editable: true, width: 100,
                        edittype: 'custom',
                        editoptions: {
                            custom_element: function (value, options) {
                                var elemStr = '<div>', newel, width;
                                if (options.id === options.name) {
                                    // form edit
                                    elemStr += '<input class="FormElement" size="' +
                                            options.size + '"' + ' id="' + options.id + '"';
                                }
                                else { // inline edit
                                    width = getColumnByName(grid, options.name).width - 2;
                                    elemStr += '<input class="FormElement" ' +
' style="width:' + width + 'px" ' + ' id="' + options.id + '_x"';
                                }

                                elemStr += ' value="' + value + '"/>';
                                elemStr += '<ul id="Xsuggestions" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul></div>';
                                newel = $(elemStr)[0];
                                setTimeout(function () {

                               $('#Xsuggestions').listview().listview('refresh');
                                    input_autocomplete(newel, options.id + '_x');
                                }, 100);
                                return newel;
                            },
                            custom_value: function (elem) {
                                return elem.find("input").val();
                            }
                        }
                    },

                { name: 'Category', index: 'Category', width: 50, editable: true }
                ],
                sortname: 'Name',
                ignoreCase: true,
                gridview: true,
                viewrecords: true,
                rownumbers: true,
                height: "100%",
                sortorder: "desc",
                pager: '#pager',
                editurl: 'clientArray',
                ondblClickRow: function (id, ri, ci) {
                    grid.jqGrid('editRow', id, true, null, null, 'clientArray', {});
                },
                onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    if (id && id !== lastSel) {
                        if (typeof lastSel !== "undefined") {
                            grid.jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSel);
                        }
                        lastSel = id;
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        var getColumnByName = function (grid, columnName) {
            var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), i = 0, l = cm.length;
            for (; i < l; ++i) {
                if (cm[i].name === columnName) {
                    return cm[i];
                }
            }
            return null;
        };

        function input_autocomplete(newel, id) {
            var input = $("input", newel);
            //if (input.length === 0) {
            //    return;
            //}
            input[0].ischanged = false;
            input.autocomplete({
                target: $('#Xsuggestions'),
                source: autocompleteData,
                callback: function (e) {
                    var $a = $(e.currentTarget);
                    $('#' + id).val($a.data('autocomplete').label);
                    $('#' + id).autocomplete('clear');
                    input[0].ischanged = true;
                },
                link: '#',
                //link: 'target.html?term=',
                minLength: 1
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="mainPage">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="searchField">
                    <ul id="suggestions" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="list"><tbody><tr><td /></tr></tbody></table>
        <div id="pager"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var autocompleteData = $.parseJSON('[{"value":"AL","label":"Alabama"},{"value":"AK","label":"Alaska"},{"value":"CA","label":"California"},{"value":"CO","label":"Colorado"},{"value":"CT","label":"Connecticut"},{"value":"NC","label":"North Carolina"},{"value":"ND","label":"North Dakota"},{"value":"NI","label":"Northern Marianas Islands"},{"value":"OH","label":"Ohio"},{"value":"OK","label":"Oklahoma"},{"value":"OR","label":"Oregon"},{"value":"PA","label":"Pennsylvania"},{"value":"PR","label":"Puerto Rico"},{"value":"RI","label":"Rhode Island"},{"value":"WV","label":"West Virginia"},{"value":"WI","label":"Wisconsin"},{"value":"WY","label":"Wyoming"}]');

        $("#mainPage").bind("pageshow", function (e) {
            $("#searchField").autocomplete({
                target: $('#suggestions'),
                source: autocompleteData,
                callback: function (e) {
                    var $a = $(e.currentTarget);
                    $('#searchField').val($a.data('autocomplete').label);
                    $("#searchField").autocomplete('clear');
                },
                link: 'target.html?term=',
                minLength: 1
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You get the error "custom_value is undefined message" because the code of `custom_element` very buggy. It contains many errors. I could write you how one can fix it, but I don't want start the discussion about the usage `autocomplete` from `jqm.autoComplete-1.5.2.js`. It is not the subject of my current interest.

Comment: @Oleg custom_element and custom_value codes are created based  jquery UI autocomplete and rate control samples. So they should work. Maybe there are some changes in jqgrid which cause custom edit to stop working in this case.

Comment: They can't work because it contains many bugs (not closed `<input>` tag on `// form edit` pat, the usage of `id` of other element for `<input>`, `<ul>` which you construct will be not placed on HTML page and it stay disconnected, ... I can continue) and there are problems with the usage of `jqm.autoComplete-1.5.2.js` inside of `<td>` of some table. You should try to modify the code of usage `jqm.autoComplete-1.5.2.js` without jqGrid but inside of `<td>` of HTML `<table>`.

Comment: @Oleg. I fixed issues and updated question. Can this code improved? I dont understand this: `there are problems with the usage of jqm.autoComplete-1.5.2.js inside of <td> of some table`. I placed separate autocomplete inside table in question code. Code also works in inline edit.  Where to find information about the referenced problems ?

Comment: I don't use `jqm.autoComplete-1.5.2.js` and don't use jQuery Mobile. Thus I can't help you here.